# Обработка div'a циклом в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть кусок кода сайта.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getcities() {

    $citystart = $('.c1_2');
    $cityfinish = $('.c2_2');

    console.log($cityfinish[0].innerHTML);
    console.log($citystart[0].innerHTML);

  };
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 6) {
    getcities();
    i++;
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="odd  " d-num="1">
  <div class="c1_2 blue">Sins</div>
  <div class="c2_2">Nantes</div>
</div>

<div class="even  " d-num="2">
  <div class="c1_2 blue">Dunningen</div>
  <div class="c2_2">Kiev</div>
</div>

<div class="odd  " d-num="3">
  <div class="c1_2 blue">Tbilisi</div>
  <div class="c2_2">Pekin</div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно сделать парсер. Но для начала мне нужно выводить в консоль все названия городов по очереди.
Следовательно я написал такой JavaScript:

И в консоли я получаю
[image: loop]

Как мне получить все города по очереди. Ну чтобы скрипт пробегал не только по первому div, а по всех по очереди и записывал мне в консоль все города?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так?

```js
$(".c1_2, .c2_2").each((i, item) => console.log($(item).html()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="odd  " d-num="1">
  <div class="c1_2 blue">Sins</div>
  <div class="c2_2">Nantes</div>
</div>

<div class="even  " d-num="2">
  <div class="c1_2 blue">Dunningen</div>
  <div class="c2_2">Kiev</div>
</div>

<div class="odd  " d-num="3">
  <div class="c1_2 blue">Tbilisi</div>
  <div class="c2_2">Pekin</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!